# Top-Left Outer Corner

Tags: android, drawable

I'm developing an android app and have some trouble with a drawable.
I tried to achieve a corner like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGwHZ.jpg



I only want the red area and the white must be transparent.

(best of course as xml)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1: Define **top_left_outer_bg.xml** in drawables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="50dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

2: Add **top_left_outer_bg.xml** as background to your layout

```
android:background="@drawable/top_left_outer_bg"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help but I already tried exactly this before but the white area must be **transparent**

Comment: try `@android:color/transparent` instead `@android:color/white`

Comment: There is the problem this doesnt work because this item is transparent then and the other is fully visible **(no corner, just a rectangle)**